# What are elementary symmetric polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, symmetric-polynomials

I searched for it in the internet but the things I found were sort of complicated to me, a high school student. What I know is that if a polynomial has even number degrees, then its graph is symmetric about the y-axis, and if the degree is odd, then its graph is not symmetric about the y-axis. I would like to learn what it is and how it is seen in graphs.

Comment: Can you give a reference on where you read about them?

Comment: Wikipedia. English is not my mother language, so this may also be the reason why they looked complicated to me, and I didn't see any graphical explanation, if there is, for it there.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/symmetric-polynomials-definition/ have a look at this, perhaps this is written more clearly